# Calculate difference between days from date

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I am trying to get the difference between between two days and i have used datepicker widget in yii2 php framework

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'leaveFrom')->label('From')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'From' , 'id' => 'date1',],
                 'pluginOptions' => [
                     'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    'todayHighlight' => true,
                     'autoclose'=>true
              ]
            ]);  ?>   


<?= $form->field($model, 'leaveTo')->label('To')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'To' , 'id' => 'date2',],
                 'pluginOptions' => [
                     'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                    'todayHighlight' => true,
                     'autoclose'=>true
              ]
            ]);  ?>


<h4 id="day" align="center"></h4>
```

I am trying to calculate date difference and display in afore h4

Javascript Code:

```
<?php 
    $this->registerJs("
        function GetDays(){
            var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById('date1').value);
            var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById('date2').value);
            return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
        }
        function cal(){
            if(document.getElementById('date2')){
                document.getElementById('day').value=GetDays();
            }
        }
    ");
?>
```

I am unable to get the output.

Comment: Errors? Console log?

Comment: whats the date format

Comment: Don't know about Yii but to calculate date difference in PHP normally `date_diff()` is used...